# Function to go back 1 UTF-8 character?

Tags: c++

I have a function which goes forward 1 utf-8 character and returns the number of bytes it took to get there:

```
// Moves the iterator to next unicode character in the string,
//returns number of bytes skipped
template<typename _Iterator1, typename _Iterator2>
inline size_t bringToNextUnichar(_Iterator1& it,
    const _Iterator2& last) const {
    if(it == last) return 0;
    unsigned char c;
    size_t res = 1;
    for(++it; last != it; ++it, ++res) {
        c = *it;
        if(!(c&0x80) || ((c&0xC0) == 0xC0)) break;
    }

    return res;
}
```

How could I modify this so that I can go back a unicode character from an arbitrary character?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just decrement the iterator instead of incrementing it.

```
// Moves the iterator to previous unicode character in the string,
//returns number of bytes skipped
template<typename _Iterator1, typename _Iterator2>
inline size_t bringToPrevUnichar(_Iterator1& it,
    const _Iterator2& first) const {
    if(it == first) return 0;
    unsigned char c;
    size_t res = 1;
    for(--it; first != it; --it, ++res) { // Note: --it instead of ++it
        c = *it;
        if(!(c&0x80) || ((c&0xC0) == 0xC0)) break;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Utf8 can take more than 1 char.

Comment: the downvoters misunderstand. the function the OP pasted increments until it finds a character boundary. @Maz is proposing to find a character boundary in the opposite direction. The logic is all the same; you just change `++it` to `--it`. I didn't work this out in my head to know if it would work, but sounds like solid logic to me. @Maz did not imply that UTF8 is 1-char only.

Comment: If Maz was suggesting a change to the original algorithm, it's possible he's right (I haven't properly checked) because that algorithm seems to be checking the bits that indicate whether it's a start-of-character byte anyway.

Comment: @tenfour: Must admit I fell pray to this (and downvoted and commented, then realised I hadn't checked whether the logic actually works if you just decrement and un-downvoted and deleted my comment)

Answer (score 6):

[UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design) start bytes are either `0xxxxxxx` or `11xxxxxx`.  No other bytes in a UTF-8 stream match those.  From this you can design a function `boolean isStartByte(unsigned char c)`.  From there the rest is boring work with C++ iterators.  Have fun.

Answer (score 2):

In UTF-8, there are three kinds of byte...

```
0xxxxxxx : ASCII
10xxxxxx : 2nd, 3rd or 4th byte of code
11xxxxxx : 1st byte of multibyte code
```

So step back until you find an 0xxxxxxx or 11xxxxxx byte.